# Rjags Invalid parent value error with use of hyper prior

Tags: r, jags, r2jags

I'm using rjags to calculate a species abundance using an N-mixture model and count data. To capture over dispersion of my data, I used hyperpriors. But I get an

```
"Error in node S[1,1,2] Invalid parent values"
```

My guess is that I have a problem in the dimension of my prior OR one of the prior is negative, null or NA which stops the calculation of node S.

Any idea how to stop this problem ? Is it possible to initialize S?

```
model {
##  PRIORS ##

lambda[1] ~ dunif(0, 500)
lambda[2] ~ dunif(0, 500) 
p[1] ~ dunif(0, 1)
p[2] ~ dunif(0, 1)
# surdispersion
muepsomega1 ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
sigepsomega1 ~ dunif(0,100)
iomega1 ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
tauepsomega1 <- 1/(sigepsomega1*sigepsomega1) 
omega2 ~ dunif(0, 1)

## LIKELIHOOD ##
# Create a loop across all j sites
for(j in 1:nSites) {

# surdispersion sur omega 1
omega1[j] <- iomega1 + epsomega1[j]
epsomega1[j] ~ dnorm(muepsomega1,tauepsomega1)

N[1,j,1] ~ dpois(lambda[1]) 
N[2,j,1] ~ dpois(lambda[2])

for (i in 1:3) {    
  S[i,j,1] ~ dnegbin(2, 1) 
  } # end loop i
for(t in 2:nYears) {
  # Estimate survivorship (between year survival)
  S[1,j,t] ~ dnegbin(omega1[j], N[1,j,t-1])  
  S[2,j,t] ~ dnegbin(omega2, N[2,j,t-1]) 

  N[1,j,t] <- S[1,j,t] 
  N[2,j,t] <- S[2,j,t] 
  } # end loop t in 2:years

# Loop across sampling replicates to estimate detection
for (t in 1:nYears){
  for(k in 1:nReps){
    n[1,j,k,t] ~ dnegbin(p[1], N[1,j,t]) 
    n[2,j,k,t] ~ dnegbin(p[2], N[2,j,t]) 

   } # end loop k nreps
  } # end loop j sites
}
```

This is how I call the model:

```
#Model file
modFile = "model/2016-07-12/model_Nmix.R"

inits <- function(){
list('lambda' =c(1,1), 'p'= c(1,1),'omega2' = 1,'iomega1'=1, 'muepsomega1'= 1, 'sigepsomega1'= 1, 'epsomega1'=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)) } # size epsomega1 is length(nSites)=7

 # Compile the model
 require(rjags)
 abundance.out <- jags.model(file=modFile, data=data,n.chains = 3, n.adapt = 3000)
```

Comment: I ran my code to just look at what epsomega1 and iomega1 produced (as my main point is to produce omega1), and they are both often negative. Any idea how to avoid negative values (exp, log apart)??

Comment: What is `S` in this case?  Is it supplied as data or is it a latent variable?

Answer (score 0):

Let epsomega1 and iomega1 come from distributions that don't have any probability density over negative values. Gamma, uniform, log-normal, or truncated normal distributions are candidates, and your choice should depend on what you think the most correct model specification actually is.